# Can I play Saints Row: The Third co-op with PC and PS3?

Tags: pc, ps3, saints-row-the-third

I have Saints Row: The Third for PS3 and PC(steam). Is there any way that I can play co-op with PC and PS3 over lan?

Comment: what does that do?

Comment: No, PS3 Saints Row players cannot play with Steam Saints Row players.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At the time of writing, there is no such ability to play with PC Users on the PS3 for that game.

Furthermore, you can also not play with users of the low violence version (Germany) of SR3 and the other way around.